# Homotopy of right action on left-invariant differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, homotopy-theory, differential-forms

I came across this problem from an old problem set on topics in Lie theory but I don't really know how to approach

> > Let G be a compact connected Lie group and let $\nu$ be the normalized Haar measure on G ($\nu$ is unique up to multiplication by positive constants), show that, for each element $g\in G$, there exists a homotopy between the identity map and the operator $\omega \mapsto  \int_GR^*_{g}(\omega)d\nu $ acting on left-invariant differential forms.

I first thought of the right action induced by the elements in the codomain of the exponential map from $Lie(G)$ to $G$, but I am not quite sure how can this map induce an endomorphism on differential forms that is homotopic to the identity? (in other words, I want to somehow come up with a linear map T such that $R_g + \{d,T\} = Id$ , where $R_g$ denotes right-translation, $\{,\}$ is the anti-commutator operation). Even then, I don't know how to proceed.

Any help is tremendously appreciated :)

Comment: Can you use a path $\gamma : g\to e$ in $G$ to get the homotopy ? (taking $H(\omega, t) = \int_G R_{\gamma (t)}^*(\omega) d\nu$)

Comment: Connected manifolds are automatically path-connected : $G$ is assumed to be connected (and a Lie group), hence it is path-connected

Comment: Oh so sorry, I forgot this basic fact. I guess my other question how is $\int_G \omega d\nu$  the identity operator on forms? and lastly, how does the right translation of an element in the image of $exp$ induce an endomorphism on forms that is homotopic to the identity? My apology if all these were clear and thank you for your comment.

Comment: $\omega$ does not depend on $g$ and the integral is $d\nu(g)$, so the result is $\nu(G)\omega$. However the Haar measure is chosen to have $\nu(G) =1 $ for compact groups. And just to clarify, your last question is about an algebraic homotopy, right ?